# How do I find the inverse Fourier transform of a function that is separable into a radial and an angular part?

Tags: fourier-analysis, spherical-coordinates, spherical-harmonics

I need to take the inverse Fourier transform of a function that is initially specified in spherical coordinates: 
$f(r, \theta, \phi) = \int_{R^3}F(k, \Theta,\Phi)e^{i\vec{k}\vec{r}}k^2sin(\Theta)dkd\Theta d\Phi$.

My function is separable into a radial and an angular part: $F(k,\Theta,\Phi)=R(k)A(\Theta,\Phi)$.

As an answer to a previous post: [How do I find the Fourier transform of a function that is separable into a radial and an angular part?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34167/how-do-i-find-the-fourier-transform-of-a-function-that-is-separable-into-a-radial/34171#34171) joriki tipped me (thanks!) on how I could expand the plane wave term into spherical waves:

$e^{i\vec{k}\vec{r}}=4\pi\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}i^lj_l(kr)\sum_{m=-l}^{+l}Y_{l,m}^*(\theta, \phi)Y_{l,m}(\Theta, \Phi)$

where $j_l$ is the spherical Bessel function and $Y_{l,m}$ is the Spherical Harmonic of degree l and order m.

Plugging this expression into the inverse Fourier transform I get:
$f(r, \theta,\phi)=4\pi\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}i^l[\int_{0}^{\infty}R(k)j_l(kr)k^2dk][\sum_{m=-l}^{+l}Y_{l,m}^*(\theta, \phi)\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}A(\Theta, \Phi)Y_{l,m}(\Theta, \Phi)sin(\Theta)d\Theta d\Phi]$

I guess the last two integrals equals the coefficients in a real spherical harmonic expansion of A (?):
$A(\Theta,\Phi)=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=-l}^{+l}A_{l,m}Y_{l,m}$, where $A_{l,m}=\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}A(\Theta, \Phi)Y_{l,m}(\Theta, \Phi)sin(\Theta)d\Theta d\Phi$

Therefore:
$f(r, \theta,\phi)=4\pi\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}i^l[\int_{0}^{\infty}R(k)j_l(kr)k^2dk][\sum_{m=-l}^{+l}A_{l,m}Y_{l,m}^*(\theta, \phi)]$

It seems the tricky part is the $\int_{0}^{\infty}R(k)j_l(kr)k^2dk$ term.
Any ideas on how to proceed with this?

Thanks in advance for any answers!